# Wagtail create custom StreamField block from field?

Tags: python, django, field, block, wagtail

I've created custom `MarkdownField` and `MarkdownPanel` classes following [this](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/wagtail-tutorials-8-add-markdown-support/) tutorial:

```
from django.db.models import TextField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.utils.widgets import WidgetWithScript

from wagtail.core.blocks import FieldBlock

class MarkdownField(TextField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MarkdownField, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MarkdownPanel(FieldPanel):
    def __init__(self, field_name, classname="", widget=None, **kwargs):
        super(MarkdownPanel, self).__init__(
            field_name,
            classname=classname,
            widget=widget,
            **kwargs
        )

        if self.classname:
            if 'markdown' not in self.classname:
                self.classname += "markdown"
        else:
            self.classname = "markdown"
```

And they work really well as fields:

[image: custom markdown field working well]

My goal is to be able to make a custom Block to use it within a StreamField on a page model like this:

```
class TestPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('markdown', MarkdownBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]

    api_fields = [
        APIField('body')
    ]
```

So I've tried to create a custom Block class as per the [Wagtail docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#custom-block-types):

```
... (MarkdownField and MarkdownPanel classes defined above)

class MarkdownBlock(FieldBlock):
    def __init__(self, field_name, classname="", widget=None, **kwargs):
        self.field = MarkdownField()
        super(MarkdownPanel, self).__init__(
            field_name,
            classname=classname,
            widget=widget,
            **kwargs
        )
```

But I'm met with this error during `makemigrations`:

```
File "*******/cms/home/models.py", line 65, in TestPage
    ('markdown', MarkdownBlock()),
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'field_name'
```

I know I'm doing something wrong here, but the documentation doesn't have much advice beyond a basic example and I'm not sure how to properly communicate with my `MarkdownField` class. I've only seen examples of custom blocks that use combinations of existing blocks, not custom fields. Any help to turn my markdown field into a block would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your definition for `MarkdownBlock` doesn't match the example in the docs - it looks like you've copied and pasted the definition for `MarkdownPanel`. The correct class definition would be something like:

```
class MarkdownBlock(FieldBlock):
    def __init__(self, required=True, help_text=None, **kwargs):
        self.field = MarkdownField(required=required, help_text=help_text)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Also, note that `FieldBlock` wraps form fields, not model fields; `MarkdownField` as defined here is a model field (it inherits from `django.db.models.TextField`) so using this as the field won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm getting an error now saying that "required" is unexpected. — super(MarkdownField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'